# How can limited span class item list in Laravel

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

Limit to item list:
[image: Limit to item list]

More Description from the Pics:
[image: More Description from the Pics]

I want to limited max item list at Laravel, As you if select all filter in admin panel, its look like this. So how can limited first 5 item to popular filters ?

```
 <div class="g-attributes">
                <span class="attr-title" style="color: orange"><b><i class="icofont-medal"></i> {{$translate_attribute->name ?? ""}}:</b> </span>
                @foreach($termsByAttribute as $term )
                    @php $translate_term = $term->translateOrOrigin(app()->getLocale()) @endphp
                    <span class="item {{$term->slug}} term-{{$term->id}}" style="color: green" >{{$translate_term->name}}</span>
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Collection's [take()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-take) method to grab the first 5 elements:

```php
@foreach($termsByAttribute->take(5) as $term)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isnt very clear, but I am assuming that you want to be able retrieve the last 5 rows of the table, in your controller, you can get the records like this

```
$termsByAttribute = Table::latest()->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: thank you for quick relpy. Accualy i dont wanna any change on controllers. Because if i make any changes on controllers, it will affect the listing on the hotel detail page. 

please check it this picture: https://imgur.com/a/wV6FTl1